# Artin's "Versal Deformations and Algebraic stacks": Question concerning proof of Theorem 3.3

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, algebraic-stacks

I have been reading Artin's paper titled "Versal deformations and algebraic stacks" and am a bit confused about a statement he makes in the proof of Theorem 3.3, in the first few lines of pg. 171: Here Artin claims that the module $\operatorname{Der}_{\mathcal{O}_S}(R, M(n))$ of derivations into a finite, nilpotent $A_0$-module $M(n)$ is a *finite-length* $A_0$-module. Here $A_0$ is a reduced, Henselian, noetherian, local $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra, $\mathcal{O}_S$ is the local ring of a scheme $S$, and $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra.

How does he conclude that $\operatorname{Der}_{\mathcal{O}_S}(R, M(n))$  is a finite-length $A_0$-module?

Note that $A_0$ is not necessarily Artinian.